# I applied smart docking layout api in my C# project after that html drag and drop not working

Tags: javascript

the docking layout
https://www.htmlelements.com/demos/docking-layout/visual-studio-style/#toc-onclose

the html  drag and drop api
https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

html drag and drop api Script

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drag(ev) {


    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text_id", ev.target.id);
    
   
    dragsid = ev.target.id.split('_')[1];
    dragfid = ev.target.id.split('_')[2];
    

}
function drop(ev) {
   
    ev.preventDefault();
    

    data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text_id");
    dragsid = data.split('_')[1];
    dragfid = data.split('_')[2];
    dragftype = data.split('_')[3];
}
```

---

### drag and drop html

```
ul.setAttribute("ondrop", "drop(event)");
        ul.setAttribute("ondragover", "allowDrop(event)");
```

---

### docking layout script

```
function  folder(id) {
   
    folderid = id.split('-')[0];
    foldername = id.split('-')[1];
    foldertype = id.split('-')[2];
    //#region dock   
     
    dockinglayout = document.querySelector('smart-docking-layout');
    folderWindowObject =
        {
            type: 'LayoutPanel',
            id: 'Id' + folderid,
            label: foldername,
            items: [{
                label: foldername,
                content: '<div id="card ' + folderid + '" ></div>'
            }],
            tabPosition: 'hidden'
        };
    dockinglayout.insertLayoutLeft(folderWindowObject);
};
```

### dokcing layout html

```
 <body  >
        <smart-docking-layout auto-load-state>
         </smart-docking-layout>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `allowDrop`, `drag`, and `drop` in your code?

Comment: Don't use w3schools.com for anything - it's a trash website filled with outdated and bad advice. It isn't as bad as it used to be (back when they had PHP code to copy+paste filled with serious SQL injection vulnerabilities), but reading it today still feels like I've been timewarped back to 2005.

Comment: @Dai I have updated code.I am using drag and drop on table row having <ul>
 before aplying docking layout it was working fine but maybe its not working because of docking layout dragging. I am not sure about it